# DynamoDB query filter with condition

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am able to retrieve data from dynamoDB using this code, but how to get data when some sort of condition is needed?

For Example: [IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtnWW.png) , Here I want to filter query using 'CONTAINS' condition, How to fetch data in this case?

```
@Repository
public class DynamoDBRepo {

    @Resource(name = "dynamoDBMapper")
    DynamoDBMapper dbMapper;

    public List<ApiData> getDetails() {

        List<ApiData> listing = new ArrayList<>();
        QueryResultPage<ApiData> itemList;


        Map<String,String> expAttributeName = new HashMap<>();
        expAttributeName.put("#Id","Id");
        Map<String, AttributeValue> expAttributeValue = new HashMap<>();
        expAttributeValue.put(":Id",new AttributeValue().withS("Api_V3"));


        DynamoDBQueryExpression<LaunchApiData> retrieveQuery = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<ApiData>()
                .withKeyConditionExpression("#Id=:Id")
                .withExpressionAttributeNames(expAttributeName)
                .withExpressionAttributeValues(expAttributeValue)
                .withScanIndexForward(false);

        try {
            itemList = dbMapper.queryPage(ApiData.class, retrieveQuery);
            listing = itemList.getResults();
        }
        catch (ResourceArnNotFoundException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        catch (HttpServerErrorException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return listing;
    }
}
```